# Inheriting from std::true_type vs static constexpr const bool member

Tags: c++

I know this is not a very pointed question.  Is there an advantage (compile time, dependencies, debug symbol sizes, usability, readability etc) of using one over another?

```
template < typename T >
struct IsSharedPtr : std::false_type
{
};
```

vs

```
template < typename T >
struct IsSharedPtr
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

A related question...

```
template < typename T, typename Enabler >
struct S;

template < typename T >
struct S < T, std::true_type >{};

template < typename T >
struct S < T, std::false_type >{};
```

vs

```
template < typename T, bool enabler >
struct S;

template < typename T >
struct S < T, true >{};

template < typename T >
struct S < T, false >{};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inheriting from `true_type`/`false_type` will already provide you with corresponding `value` member, function call operator and implicit conversion to bool. In addition, if you will use inheritance, your type would be eligible for tag dispatch, which is often clearer and easier than SFINAE:

```
namespace detail 
{
template <typename T>
void do_work(T& foo, std::true_type);

template <typename T>
void do_work(T& foo, std::false_type);
}

template <typename T>
void do_something(T& foo) 
{
    //Selects overload depending on type of IsSharedPtr<T>
    detail::do_work(foo, IsSharedPtr<T>{})
}
```

Comment: Note you can also dispatch on a second template argument, which could be somewhat stricter because type (trait) conversions aren't involved in selecting the function.